# How to make laravel 5.2 pagination work(count) on just main table records not include the join tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
$employees  =   DB::table('users')
                    ->leftJoin('assigned_branches','assigned_branches.user_id','=','users.id')
                    ->leftJoin('assigned_geo_infos','assigned_geo_infos.id' ,'=','assigned_branches.region_branch_id')
                    ->leftJoin('user_customers','user_customers.user_id','=','assigned_branches.user_id')
                    ->leftJoin('customers','customers.id','=','user_customers.customer_id')
                    ->whereIn('assigned_geo_infos.project_id',$assigned_projects_ids)
                    ->where([['users.office_staff',0],['users.active',$filter]])
                    ->select('assigned_geo_infos.*','assigned_geo_infos.id as info_id','assigned_geo_infos.name as info_name','assigned_branches.*','assigned_branches.level as region_branch_level','users.*','customers.customer_name')
                    ->paginate(15);
```

So here i want to pagination process or calculation on just users table not on other table means join table.According to users total count should be 2 but due to join its is giving total page 8. Or is there any other solution in which i can get all join table records as sub array of main table record array.

Comment: Maybe you should use `groupBy('users.id')`?

Answer (score 0):

Use groupBy() method, to group the results:

```
$employees  =   DB::table('users')
                    ->leftJoin('assigned_branches','assigned_branches.user_id','=','users.id')
                    ->leftJoin('assigned_geo_infos','assigned_geo_infos.id' ,'=','assigned_branches.region_branch_id')
                    ->leftJoin('user_customers','user_customers.user_id','=','assigned_branches.user_id')
                    ->leftJoin('customers','customers.id','=','user_customers.customer_id')
                    ->whereIn('assigned_geo_infos.project_id',$assigned_projects_ids)
                    ->where([['users.office_staff',0],['users.active',$filter]])
                    ->select('assigned_geo_infos.*','assigned_geo_infos.id as info_id','assigned_geo_infos.name as info_name','assigned_branches.*','assigned_branches.level as region_branch_level','users.*','customers.customer_name')
                    ->groupBy('users.id')
                    ->paginate(15);
```

Comment: by using group_by i cannot get my desire results of joins

Comment: is there any other way by which i can just implement the pagination on just users table while using joins ??